# w / b in vim is including . in the word

Tags: vim

It seems like vim's concept of word changed in the last couple of days for me. I've installed some plugins .. CtrlP is the latest, but I'd be surprised if it was the cause.

```
obj.prop
```

it's treating that as 1 `word` (also `WORD`, but that's good) when i use either <kbd>w</kbd> or <kbd>b</kbd>. I've checked out `:map` and I don't see anything suspicious in there.

Oh man I thought I just had it with `'iskeyword'`, but:

`:set iskeyword?` response:

[image: :set iskeyword? response]

Any ideas what could cause this behavior? Or suggestions to troubleshoot?

Comment: Another thought - is the setting specific to a certain file type/extension?  Maybe a plugin is trying to "help" and sets it for certain file types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is indeed the `iskeyword` setting.  That `.` on the end appears to be the problem. It currently indicates that `.` is a valid character in a "word".  Try changing it to:

```
:set iskeyword=@,48-57,_,192-255,$,-,#
```

Comment: You're correct. How can I tell which file last modified this setting so I can change it permanently? It's not in .vimrc (nor the shorthand 'isk').

Comment: Good question.  I would attempt just setting it explicitly in vimrc.  My suspicion based on what you are saying is that one of the plugins must be changing it dynamically when it loads (seems like bad manners). Aside from removing/adding them one-by-one and checking it, I'm not sure how to deduce which one is the culprit.

Comment: @tmack Use `:verbose set iskeyword?` to find where it was last set.